# What does μὴ ἐγκακεῖν mean in Luke 18:1?

Tags: greek, luke, new-testament

What does μὴ ἐγκακεῖν mean in Luke 18:1? (Greek text from NA27)

Note ἐγκακέω is the preposition ἔν combined with the verb κακέω.   In BDAG “ἐγκακέω is defined as 1. *become weary, tired* w. ptc. foll. … 2. *lose heart, despair …; be afraid*, of women in child-birth …” (1979 ed., p 215).  The verb κακέω doesn’t occur in the New Testament, but the adjective κακός, ή, όν (*bad, worthless, inferior* BDAG) does. This adjective is the opposite of καλός, ή, όν

> καλός, ή, όν: pertaining to having acceptable characteristics or functioning in an agreeable manner, often with the focus on outward form or appearance—‘good, fine.’

Louw, J. P., & Nida, E. A. (1996). Greek-English lexicon of the New Testament: based on semantic domains (electronic ed. of the 2nd edition., Vol. 1, p. 622). New York: United Bible Societies.

> κακός, ή, όν; κακῶς: pertaining to having experienced harm—‘harmed, harm, injured.’(Ibid., Vol. 1, p. 229)

An example of how these words are used, if food tastes good, it is καλός, while if food tastes bad it is κακός.

I wondering, since κακ is the root of ἐγκακέω, if this word has a fuller meaning than the translations of “to not be weary” or “to not despair” and means “to not be weary of bad, distasteful, and hurtful circumstances.”  This fuller meaning does seem to match the parable. However, the fuller meaning could also mean becoming weary of praying and viewing prayer as drudgery (e.g. Gal. 6:9; 2 Thes. 3:13). Maybe someone with a classical Greek background knows more usage of this word.

Supplemental information: The other five New Testament passages with ἐγκακέω.  In all six New Testament occurrences it has a negative adverb μὴ or οὐκ.

> Therefore, since we have this ministry because we were shown mercy,  we do not give up.   Instead, we have renounced shameful secret things, not walking  in deceit or distorting God’s message,  but commending ourselves to every person’s conscience in God’s sight by an open display of the truth.  (2 Cor. 4:1–2, ESV, translated *give up*)
>
> Therefore we do not give up.  Even though our outer person is being destroyed, our inner person is being renewed day by day. (2 Cor. 4:16, ESV, translated *give up*)
>
> So we must not get tired of doing good, for we will reap at the proper time if we don’t give up.  (Gal. 6:9, ESV, translated *get tired*)

This verse seems to not match because the object is “doing good” (καλὸν ποιοῦντες).  However, how the verb matches κακός here is the idea of letting doing good become unpleasant or distasteful, a drudgery; the opposite of the idea in cheerful giver.

> So then I ask you not to be discouraged over my afflictions on your behalf, for they are your glory. (Eph. 3:13, ESV, translated *be discouraged*)
>
> Brothers, do not grow weary in doing good. (2 Thes. 3:13, ESV, translated *grow weary*)

This has the same sense as Gal. 6:9.

Comment: By BAG do you mean BDAG?

Comment: Which Greek Text are you using please?

Comment: Greek quotes from NA27

Comment: People do not like to admit it but κακέω comes from "to shit (yourselves)" or "to smear (yourselves) with shit" as an expression of utter disdain. Compare to βδελιγμα. Not worth posting this as an answer as it will certainly get shitty votes mostly ;-)

Comment: @grammaplow - Walace mentions the fallacy of applying etymology to the meaning of a word over how the word is used.  Here how the word is used is difficult.  But, if this meaning applies, to the Jewish Paul  it would give the sense if uncleanliness according to the Law.  Thus, the idea that an attitude can make one unclean.

Comment: @grammaplow - From the context it isn't farfetched to say that this distaining attitude results in the lack of sanctification for doing good.  that is Romans 8:29

Comment: There is no fuller, unique meaning of the word in this context, it is clear. The question is making the same fallacy of trying to connect the etymology kakos with the derivative word. Like there are some ques that relate poneros (evil) to ponos (pain) https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/4415/how-should-%cf%80%ce%bf%ce%bd%ce%b7%cf%81%e1%bd%b9%cf%82-be-translated-in-matthew-711-and-why/81410#81410

Comment: @PerryWebb as we all know there are multiple seemingly irreconcilable interpretations of the most basic principles from the bible. So I let etymology to come first in my studies, the sentence/verse context second and some doctrinal interpretation third if at all. And even then, “What is truth?” Pilate asked Jh18:38. The context of clean and unclean relating to digestion (and thus immediately material to anyone) is also confirmed by Jesus's quote "20 And He said, “What comes out of a man, that defiles a man." MK7:20 and many others adding to that context.

Comment: @Michael16 pls check my answer there https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/20899/13464

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be some variation between lexicographers about this word.  The Analytical Lexicon of GNT by Friberg et al. lists three different spellings for the root verb ἐγκακέω but this should not distract us here.  However, the same lexicon offers this understanding:

> (1) strictly, *act badly* in some circumstance; with a participle
>   following, *become weary or tired* of doing something (2 Thess 3:13);
>   (2) as failing to hold out successfully, give up, become discouraged,
>   lose heart (2 Cor 4:1).

BDAG offers much more information (as expected) by offering two basic meanings.

> (1) **to loose one's motivation in continuing a desirable pattern of
>   conduct or activity, *lose enthusiasm, be discouraged*** with
>   participle following **2 Thess 3:13**; with participle preceding **Gal
>   6:9**. (Both these passages play on the opposition of "Τὸ καλός" and
>   "Τὸ κακός" in Greek-Roman thought representing civic responsibility.) 
>   οὐκ ἐγκακοῦμεν *we do not lose our enthusiasm for 'this service'* 2
>   Cor 4:1 (in contrast to falling into deceptive behavior patterns,
>   vs2); **16**.  αἰτοῦμαι μὴ ἐνκακεῖν ἐν ταῖς θλίψεσίν I ask you not to
>   be disappointed in connection with my tribulations **Eph 3:13**.  On
>   these last three. 2 Abs *give up* **Luke 18:1**.
>
> (2) **to be afraid in the face of a great difficulty, *be afraid***,
>   of women in childbirth … some would put 2 Cor 4:1, 16, Eph 3:13 here.

Thus, I believe Perry Webb is correct to sense that an important cultural component is in play in the meaning intended in Luke 18:1.  Certainly the NIV, CEV, ISV and NLT render the last phrase in Luke 18:1, "give up"; most others have either "lose heart" or "not faint".  I am inclined to agree with BDAG.

Comment: I don't think you meant Paul.

Comment: My apologies - I will correct immediately.  Thanks.